# I am lost, why color output differs everywhere?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color-profile

http://prntscr.com/ompfh8

I have read about what is sRGB and some color modes. I know where to edit color mode Edit - Color Settings. But after spending a lot of time i am unable to synchronize my colors in 3 points !

1st point - Illustrator palete
2nd point - Illustrator artboard
3rd point - browser

All 3 points shows different hex codes. I am using Instant Eyedropper for comparing.

Lets start simple. How do i get same color on artboard as in color palete in Illustrator ? I tried CMYK/RGB Document color mode. Played with View - Proof colors. No help

On screenshot above u can see difference

Comment: also for no reason my circle has opacity even with opacity: 100% selected on it

Comment: khm khm. i knew about opacity changing colors. i searched for it. but didn't know there could be opacity on a fill property ))) now colors on palete and object are same

Comment: Is your eyedropper set to point sample or average? Also be aware the color **picker** in Illustrator is controlled by the OS *far more* than it is by the application. AI's color picker is **not** like Photoshop's color picker.